# Accept Google Cookies

Tags: python, selenium

I want to use Python's Selenium to accept the cookies of Google. But the ids and everything are at random values. So, how do I do for example

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="L2AGLb"]').click()
```

?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click a particular location in x,y (that is if x,y, is known), but in your case x & y will a be constant unless you are resizing windows.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
el=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(string(), 'Lucky')]")[0]

action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(el, 5, 5)
```

*use this line from a id that doesnt change within the page*

```
action.click()
action.perform()
```

You wouldn't have a problem if the click is offset with respect to an element that doesn't alter its ID.